# Mimic SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a middle ware tier between my applications and database (which is SQL Server) and I don't want to change code in clients. I just wanted to listen on the same port as SQL Server listens and process all the queries coming in and send proper response back to client.

I created a socket and listened on it, but it didn't work. My problem is I don't know how SQL Server manages connections.

Any Idea?

Regards,

Comment: If you have the client prgm's source, maybe it's more simple to add some debug functions to it.

Comment: Sounds more like a "man in the middle" attack than middleware!

Comment: I am implementing something like data base server which MySQL clients can connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're going to have to implement [TDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream). I've not had to do it myself, but there's an [MS spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523%28v=prot.13%29.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is reverse engineer the wire level protocol used by sql server.

This is a massive protocol. It can change with minor fix levels. It can change drastically from release to release.

Its not impossible but its a major project and certainly a much more major project then solving whatever problem you think you have by doing something else.